# How do I mock static property Groovy?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking

I saw a lot of examples how to mock a static method in a class.

I want to mock a static property of the class, that's initialized in its definition.

Something like:

```
class MyClass {
   private static log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
}
```

I want to mock log property, in order that in my test it should be null, and it should not initialize itself.

Comment: In your setup() of the testcase you can directly write MyClass.log=null ?

Comment: no, since it initializes the property first, then it puts there null. I don't want it to go to the "LogFactory.getLog" method.

Comment: you can use the static block. Try using the following code: static{Myclass.metaClass.static.getLog = {
   return "what you need"
}}

Answer (score 1):

Make static getter method :

```
static def getLog() {
    return log
}
```

Use `metaClass.static`to mock method:

```
Myclass.metaClass.static.getLog = {
   return "what you need"
}
```

Comment: It is still problematic, since it still tries to call the LogFactory.getLog() method to initialize the property.

Comment: You suppose u should delete `private static log = LogFactory.getLog(this)` and replace it with satatic method `getLog()` so it will not be initialized when class load.

Comment: That class I prefer not to change. It's used already from several places. Thanks!

Comment: Inteface of class will not change if you make this changes. Nothing will change for classes outside. Just try.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to 'log' as a property, but it's actually not. Assuming that MyClass is a Groovy class, then a property is declared without a private or public modifier, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
}
```

What you have is a private static variable with an initializer. In this case, no property access methods are generated, and the variable is not considered a property.

Because it's a private variable with an initializer, and you state that you don't want to change the class, you cannot stop the initializer from running. So the best thing to do here is to mock out the getLog() call to return null. A simple but crude approach would be:

```
LogFactory.metaClass.static.getLog = {
    return null
}
```

but this will kill all log lookup in the whole application. This could be OK for a simple unit test, but a more specific solution is to use Groovy mocks (MockFor and StubFor), which will allow you to mock the getLog call in a specific block of code. You can find out more [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Mocks)

As a matter of interest, why do you not want the log variable initialized?